# How can I load change settings from a file for different route in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, routes

I have a basic node.js express site that uses a config file to set up variables for `ejs` templating and all works well.

I would like to load a different set of values if a particular route is used.

I have tried the following naive approach.

**app.js** partial

```
var config = require('./config');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.render('body-index', {
    success: null,
    config: config,
    error: null});
})

//Then for a target route

app.get('/world', function (req, res) {
  //This part messes up
  config = require('./config_world');

  res.render('body-world', {
    success: null,
    config: config,
    error: null});
})
```

**config.js**

```
var config = {};

config.name = 'Name 1';

module.exports = config;
```

**config_world.js**

```
var config = {};

config.name = 'A Different Name';

module.exports = config;
```

### Update

I relised that I need to load in the required file on app boot to have the values available. I added the first line and adjusted my route so all works as I wanted now.
**app.js** partial

```
var configDefault = require('./configWorld');

app.get('/world', function (req, res) {

  res.render('body-world', {
    success: null,
    config: configDefault,
    error: null});
})
```

Is this the best way to supply different config sets for template engines?

Comment: what is your question?  does your code work?

Comment: "How can I load changed settings from a file for different route in Nodejs?" I have a default route that loads one set of settings and another I want to change. I am about to amend my question as I spotted what I was doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, it is advisable not to declare your module import (i.e. using the require statement) in your route. Using ES6, the following is a good practice.

```
const configDefault = require('./configDefault');
const configWorld = require('./configWorld');

app.get('/default', function (req, res) {

 res.render('default-world', {
  success: null,
  config: configDefault,
  error: null});
 });

}

app.get('/world', function (req, res) {

 res.render('body-world', {
  success: null,
  config: configWorld,
  error: null});
 });

}
```